# Getting only the exterior boundary of a 'donut-shaped' GeoSeries object

Tags: geopandas, boundaries

`GeoSeries.boundary()` finds the entire object's perimeter, so I supposed that wouldn't work.
I made my GeoSeries donut-like shape using `unary_union` of smaller GeoSeries objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `exterior` method.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
from geopandas import GeoSeries

donut = Point(5 ,5).buffer(5, 2).difference(Point(5, 5).buffer(3, 2))
print(donut)

# OUTPUT
# POLYGON ((10 5, 8.535.. 1.464..., 5.000... 0, 1.464... 1.464..., 0 4.999..., 1.464... 8.535..., 5 10, 8.535... 8.535..., 10 5), #exterior
#          (8 5, 7.121... 7.121..., 5 8, 2.878... 7.121..., 2 5, 2.878... 2.878..., 5. 2, 7.121... 2.878..., 8 5)) # interior
```

[image]

```
donut_gs = GeoSeries(donut)
print(donut_gs.exterior)

# OUTPUT
# 0    LINEARRING (10 5, 8.535.. 1.464..., ....
# dtype: geometry
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer and edit.
Just one question: what does the '[0]' passed in donut_gs.exterior[0] do?
I only see that I get the printed object in one case (when passing [0]) and only the object's  description ('linearring') in the other.

Comment: I initially wasn't understanding why there should be 1 row; it took me a while before I finally noticed that even though the entries in the linear ring (10.00000 5.00000, 8.53553 1.46447,...) are not separated nicely by commas the way we usually expect [e.g. (10,5) (8.53,1.46), ..] each entry is still representing a single point - just space separated instead!
Thanks again!